# boost::python: How can I override a static property?

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I have a base class and a derived class, both of which have an identically named static method. Is it possible to expose both of them while keeping the names the same? This compiles, but throws an exception upon import of the module.

```
struct Base
{
    static std::string say_hi() { return "Hi"; }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    static std::string say_hi() { return "Hello"; }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(HelloBoostPython)
{
    namespace py = boost::python;

    py::class_<Base>("Base").add_static_property("say_hi", &Base::say_hi);

    py::class_<Derived, py::bases<Base>>("Derived").add_static_property("say_hi", &Derived::say_hi);
}
```

Upon import:

```
>>> import HelloBoostPython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: initialization of HelloBoostPython raised unreported exception
```

Changing the last line to a different name works, but I'd rather have the base class's property be overridden:

```
py::class_<Derived, py::bases<Base>>("Derived").add_static_property("say_hello", &Derived::say_hi);
```

This works, but I get class methods instead of properties:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(HelloBoostPython)
{
    namespace py = boost::python;

    py::object base = py::class_<Base>("Base");
    base.attr("say_hi") = Base::say_hi;

    py::object derived = py::class_<Derived, py::bases<Base>>("Derived");
    derived.attr("say_hi") = Derived::say_hi;
}
```

This will give me properties but won't work in the general case if the static methods aren't constant:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(HelloBoostPython)
{
    namespace py = boost::python;

    py::object base = py::class_<Base>("Base");
    base.attr("say_hi") = Base::say_hi();

    py::object derived = py::class_<Derived, py::bases<Base>>("Derived");
    derived.attr("say_hi") = Derived::say_hi();
}
```

Hmm

Comment: What is the “unreported exception”?  (You can use [`PyErr_WriteUnraisable`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_WriteUnraisable), for instance.)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how `Boost Python` is exposing static property and how that behaves in `Python` it looks like that is a bug in `Boost Python`.

I'm getting following error when i try to import the problematic example:

```
>>> import HelloBoostPython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>>
```

The attribute can't be set because there is a clash in the derived class. `Derived` class first inherits `say_hi` property from `Base` and then tries to define it's own. This can be easily verified by changing `say_hi` to `say_hello` in the `Derived` class as was done by the author:

`py::class_<Derived, py::bases<Base>>("Derived").add_static_property("say_hello", &Derived::say_hi);`

Then we can see the following data descriptors `help(HelloBoostPython.Derived)`:

```
    class Derived(Base)
...
...
     |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  Data descriptors defined here:
     |
     |  say_hello
     |
     |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  Data and other attributes defined here:
     |
     |  __instance_size__ = 24
     |
     |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  Data descriptors inherited from Base:
     |
     |  say_hi
...
...
```

However when we define similar in python:

```
class Base(object):

    def get_say_hi(self):
        return "hi"

    say_hi = property(get_say_hi)

class Derived(Base):

    def get_say_hi(self):
        return "hello"

    say_hi = property(get_say_hi)
```

We can see that here we have only `say_hi` defined in `Derived`:

```
class Derived(Base)
...
...
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |
 |  say_hi
 |
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from Base:
 |
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
(END)
```

And after removing `say_hi` from `Derived`:

```
class Base(object):

    def get_say_hi(self):
        return "hi"

    say_hi = property(get_say_hi)

class Derived(Base):
    None
```

We get it inherited from `Base` then:

```
class Derived(Base)
...
...
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from Base:
 |
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |
 |  say_hi
(END)
```

Comment: Boost.Python's static properties are different than Python's property, though. The former resolves on the class and its instances, while the later only resolves on its instances and returns itself for the class. For example, `Base.say_hi` would returns `hi` for the former, and returns a `property` instance for the later, etc. That said, a simple solution to the issue is to actually bind the property to the derived class directly to avoid any kind of resolution issues. I've posted an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when Boost.Python's metaclass attempts to declare and set `Derived.say_hi`, it resolves to `Base.say_hi.__set__` because it is an existing class descriptor inherited from `Base`. A solution, could be to bind the property to your `Derived` class yourself. E.g.

```
namespace py = boost::python;

py::class_<Base>("Base").add_static_property("say_hi", &Base::say_hi);

py::class_<Derived, py::bases<Base>> Derived_("Derived");

PyDict_SetItemString(
    py::downcast<PyTypeObject>(Derived_.ptr())->tp_dict,
    "say_hi",
    Derived_.attr("__base__").attr("__dict__")["say_hi"].attr("__class__")(
        py::make_function(&Derived::say_hi)
    ).ptr()
);
```

That way `say_hi` is bound directly to the `Derived` class as a `Boost.Python.StaticProperty` instance. Now the following code:

```
print(Base().say_hi, Base.say_hi, Derived().say_hi, Derived.say_hi)
```

Would properly prints:

```
Hi Hi Hello Hello
```